# XmlPullPaser skip one Tag for Rss Reader in Android

Tags: android, rss, xmlpullparser

I am developing a reader for an rss feed wordpress.
The problem is that it is picking up the image of the gravatar and should not.

```
public class RssParser {

    public List<RssItem> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean insideItem = false;
        String imageUrl = null;
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();

            if (name.equals("item")) {
                insideItem = true;
            } else if (name.equals("media:content")) {
                if (insideItem)
                    imageUrl = readImage(parser);
            }

            if (imageUrl != null) {
                RssItem item = new RssItem(imageUrl);
                items.add(item);
                imageUrl = null;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    private String readImage(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "media:content");
        return parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
    }
}
```

I wonder how I can do to skip this "media: content" containing gravatar image.

Example here as a part of my rss code.

```
<media:content url="https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7d261705b92edb50eaca05ed63ca453e?s=96&#38;d=identicon&#38;r=G" medium="image">
    <media:title type="html">renangueiros</media:title>
</media:content>

<media:content url="https://correntesproinfo.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/duvidas.jpg?w=300" medium="image">
    <media:title type="html">duvidas</media:title>
</media:content>
```

I wish my code skip the first tag `media:content` that contains the image of gravatar, and only return the second that contains url of the image I want use.

Comment: Do you mean that your code could not recognise the "media:content" tags and you wish to recognise it so as to pick up the gravatar image?

Comment: here is the link to my feed. https://correntesproinfo.wordpress.com/feed/

Comment: If I wanted my code ignored the gravatar image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the urls to the gravatar image are those which starts with `https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/` then you can just use the following code:

```
  if (name.equals("item")) {
        insideItem = true;
  } else if (name.equals("media:content")) {
        if (insideItem) {
             imageUrl = readImage(parser);
             if ((imageUrl != null) && ! imageUrl.startsWith("https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/") {
                 RssItem item = new RssItem(imageUrl);
                 items.add(item);             
             }
        }
  }
```

Separately, please note that your `insideItem` variable was not reset to false. You may wish to check for the `END_TAG` of `<item>` and do so.